# Mapping of words to stemmed words (Stem dictionary)

Tags: java, nlp, rapidminer, stemming

I want to generate a mapping of ( word-stemmed word ) which il need for my project.

I am trying to generate the mapping this way

1.i took a text ( in file 1),used rapid miner to stem all the words and saved the resulting text in another file say file 2.

2.i wrote a java program which will take file1 and file 2 as parameters,scan a word from file1 and a word from file2 and store them as a pair in a HAshset.

Will this method work perfectly? Is there any other better method to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

i answer my question again..

Yes this method is working but make sure you remove all the punctuation,/,&,#,digits ,apostrophe marks and everything except alphabets.

only then the mapping will be perfect